# How to show html data using ajax on new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { bid: z, mpid: x, pid: y, radio: b, quan: c },
    async:false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status == 'success') {
            go_success = true;
        }
        else if (data.status == 'error') {
            alert("error");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});

if (go_success) {  
    window.open(newurl.php);
}
```

want to open new pop like window on top on main page showing data being received using ajax.

pl help

Comment: Move your window.open function to where you set go_success = true;